# Explain why a composite function in which g(x) is any function, is applied to the output of any even function h(x) , f(x) is always even.

Tags: proof-verification, function-and-relation-composition

This is what I have so far, but I don't feel like its a full explanation

The even function gets rid of the negation

Since $ h(x) $ is even then $ h(x)=h(-x) for \ all \ x \ $

$ f(x) = g(h(x)) $

$ f(-x) = g(h(-x)) = g(h(x)) \ or \  g(-(-h(x))) = g(h(x)) $

therefore $  f(x) $ is even

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove that $f$, defined by $f(x) = g(h(x))$ is even. That means proving that for any $x$, you have
$$
f(x) = f(-x)
$$

The stuff you've written out in the middle is almost a proof of that. To give a real proof, start by writing out the definition of 
$$
f(-x)
$$
and simplifying. When you've done a step or two, you should be able to say "...which is just $f(x)$".

Comment: Thanks I understand what you mean but I don't really know how to explain it in words.

Comment: Very few words are needed. I'll get you started: "Let $x$ be any element of the domain. Then $f(-x) = g(h(-x)) = ..." What do you know about $h(-x)$? Can you simplify it at all?